# Returning a enum value

Tags: c#

I am having trouble inplemeting an enum into a switch case and im not sure why, I have tried the name of the values in the enumeration and also their corrosponding int values, neither work.
error:
The name 'GuessThatNumber' does not exist in the current context [NameProgram]csharp(CS0103) etc for all options.

```
using System;

public enum MenuOption{
    TestName,
    GuessThatNumber,
    Quit
}

namespace NameProgram
{
    class nameTester
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MenuOption userSelection;
            userSelection = ReadUserOption();
            Console.WriteLine(userSelection);
            do {
                switch(userSelection){
                    case TestName:
                        Console.WriteLine("please enter a name: ");
                        break;
                    case GuessThatNumber:
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess the name: ");
                        break;
                    case default:
                        break;
                }
            } while (userSelection != Quit);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static MenuOption ReadUserOption(){
            Console.WriteLine("1: Player 1 -- Test name, 2: Player 2 -- Guess name, 3: Player 2 -- Giveup (quit)");

            int number = 0;
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            return (MenuOption)(number -1);
        }

        // public static TestName(string guess){
        //     if ()
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it was C#. I corrected OP's tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name or create an alias.

#### Fully qualified name

```
     switch(userSelection){
         case MenuOption.TestName:
              Console.WriteLine("please enter a name: ");
              break;
         case MenuOption.GuessThatNumber:
              Console.WriteLine("Guess the name: ");
              break;
         default:
              break;
     }
```

#### Alias

Add one line in the using section

```
using static MenuOptions
```

Comment: I think instead of case default: should be default:

Comment: Good spot, failed to spot during c/p from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `MenuOption.TestName` instead of just `TestName`.